# How do you combine Fixtures Flask migration on Production?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been looking for a tutorial that could give guidance on should I organize my newbie Flask project's migration scripts and make them run fixtures to insert data into database. I'd  prefer using plain SQL rather than Python scripts.

As I am a newbie here I am not sure though that is the preferred way to put things there... but I guess Django has fixtures and they can utilized both in testing and in production.

Tutorials I've introduced myself only contain fixtures for testing, so no guidance from there so far.

So, how do you combine SQL fixtures with Flask's migration in production?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did a  **hack** for this and I'll post it here if anyone gets a benefit out from it.

The idea is that if there is file in `migrations/versions` directory with the same name as the migration script but ending with .sql, then this script runs it.

Place the contents below to the file which was created by `manage.py db migrate` script.

file: app.utils

```
from functools import wraps
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
import inspect


def apply_migrations_update(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        import os 

        retval = f(*args, **kwargs)

        dir_path = inspect.getfile(f)
        sqlfile = dir_path[:-3] + ".sql" 
        if os.path.isfile( sqlfile ): 
            print ("Opening .sql file {}".format(sqlfile))
            with open(sqlfile, 'r') as myfile: 
                s = sa.sql.text( myfile.read() ) 
                op.execute(s) 
            print ("SQL executed.".format(sqlfile))
        else:
            print ("No .sql file found {}".format(sqlfile))

        return retval

    return wrap
```

and file versions/*.py

```
"""a clever message describing schema changes

Revision ID: bc552c19h313
Revises: 
Create Date: 2018-11-29 16:02:37.716660

"""
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from app.utils import apply_migrations_update
#...

@apply_migrations_update
def upgrade():
```